# python standard input

Tags: python, input

In Python, how can I get data from standard input? I want to be able to specify a text file as an input to the script from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sys.stdin`. It acts like a file object, so treat it as one when you use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

print sys.stdin.read()
```

Running this by itself hangs the interpreter, but adding a pipe operator does what it should:

```
> echo "asd" | python test.py
> asd
```